# How to check for complete word in conditional regex statement?

Tags: regex, if-statement, conditional-statements

Working with this text:

```
<li><a href="html/Inpatient/3,40060.html"> Informaci<font color="red">ó</font>n para los maestros y la escuela</a></li>
```

I need a conditional statement that basically says:

If the text ' font color="red" ' appears in the link, match ' html"> '.

I've been trying the following code:

```
(?(?=font color="red")html">)
```

But the selection ends up being broken up into pieces, and the match is not made. Any ideas?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30K1m.png)

Comment: Please provide expected output

Comment: Expected output is to either match ' html"> ' or not, depending on whether or not ' font color="red" ' exists. Not really sure how else to explain it...

Comment: Else explain it is by making another code block with title 'expected output'. I update my answer in a few moment

Answer (score 1):

The proper way using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
//a[font[@color="red"]]
```

or in a shell :

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//a[font[@color="red"]]' file |
    grep -o 'html">'
```

### Output:

```
html">
```